# Generating a dropdown menu in a panel

Tags: python

i'm trying to create a simple dropdown menu inside a panel but i can't figure out why my enumproperty doesn't get drawn.
this is what I have so far:

```
import bpy

class AKA_PT_Scene_settings(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'myTools'
    bl_label = 'Scene Settings'

    scale_presets: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="Scale Presets",
        description="Select scale preset",
        items=[
            ('μm',"Micrometers","Set scene scale to micrometers"),
            ('mm',"Millimeters","Set scene scale to millimeters"),
            ('cm',"Centimeters","Set scene scale to centimeters"),
            ('m',"Meters","Set scene scale to meters"),
            ('km',"Kilometers","Set scene scale to kilometers"),
        ],
        default = 'm'
    )

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(self, "scale_presets")

# Register the panel
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(AKA_PT_Scene_settings)

# Unregister the panel
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(AKA_PT_Scene_settings)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()`
```

I'm getting no errors, and the panel shows up in the sidebar so I assume it has nothing to do with the registration part of the code. any idea?

Comment: Hello. Panels can't hold custom properties, they're interface elements only. You may want to store the properties on the current scene for example and access that in the `draw` method with `context.scene.scale_presets`

Comment: thank you Gorgious, since I successfully created a dropdown menu in the undo/redo panel I assumed it could be implemented pretty much the same way.

Comment: Indeed, but the undo panel is displaying properties of the operator you just executed, it doesn't itself possess any property